# play framework content type split

Tags: java, playframework

I want to distinguish between text/html and application/json, but my code returns always text/html.

```
public static Result GetAll() {
    List<ErrorType> dataList = ErrorType.find.where().orderBy("id asc").findList();
    title = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + "/" + title;
//html
    if (request().accepts("text/html")) {

        return ok(index.render(dataList, title));
    }
//json
    if (request().accepts("application/json")) {
        return ok(Json.toJson(dataList));
    }
//other
    return badRequest("accepts only text/html or application/json");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request accepts both `html` as well as `json` (this is the case in a lot of scenarios) then your first `if` statement for the `html` will always execute and you will return a response before getting to the if statment for the`json` part.

Comment: I tryed to change html and json in position, but now it returns alwasy json strings. Both content types are strings, is there the problem or do I have create a own method for json? If it´s possible I would prefer one method for all content types.

Comment: @AndreasFritsch That's exactly my point. The way you have structured your `if statements` are in such a way that one takes precedence over the other. This is not necessarily a bad thing. You should determine which one is more important in your application and put that one first. A lot of web apps nowadays expect/return `json` for data instead of pure `html` so I suggest giving dominance to the `json` if you're dealing with pure data. On the other hand, if you're returning `html` for rendering purposes then `html` should take dominance. Like I said, it all depends on your application.